# "Schedule of items due" meaning

Tags: exam-questions, ielts

I've practised IELTS listening and encountered the following passage:

> STUDENT:    Okay, thanks. And to clarify, what exactly is due in the
> first phase?
>
> PROFESSOR: Before the October deadline, I want your group to have
> compiled resources and then to provide some initial data analysis to
> support your claims.
>
> STUDENT:    Okay, so data analysis is due the 10th of October, and
> then the um, the
>
> PROFESSOR: - Presentation? Yes. The final phase is simply giving the
> presentation on the 5th of November.

Then there were two fields to complete:

> **Schedule of items due:**
>
> First phase: _________
> Final phase: Group _________

As I've understood from the heading 'Schedule of items due', the answers have to be connected with time. So I wrote down:

> **Schedule of items due:**
>
> First phase: **October 10th**
> Final phase: Group **November 5**

However, the correct answer is:

> **Schedule of items due:**
>
> First phase: **data analysis**
> Final phase: Group **presentation**

Why is it so? In 'Schedule of items due' heading doesn't 'due' suggest having a particular date, as in the sentence 'Final results are due Wednesday night' for example?

Comment: The question asks for the _items_ that are due, not the dates when they are due.

Comment: This must be a British understanding of *schedule*, because when I saw that word, I too assumed that it was asking for a timeline of dates.

Answer (score 1):

Q. Why is it so? **In Schedule of items due heading doesn't due suggest having a particular date, as in the sentence Final results are due Wednesday night for example?**

---

You are mixing up items and dates

**Due dates** as opposed to **Items due**

Date they are expected to arrive ..v... Expected items

---

**due date**; noun; the date by which something has to be done or paid:

**due** adjective (EXPECTED) expected (to happen, arrive, etc.) at a particular time:

**item**; noun; something that is part of a list or group of things:

All ref CED [**Due date**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/due-date)